# How would this date be translated into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, time, calendarium

I want to engrave my ring with my wedding date in Latin. The date is June 8th, 2010. Can you translate this for me?

Answer (score 5):

In classical mode this is rather complicated, but would be  abbreviated to **a.d. VI Id. Iun. A.D. MMX**, literally short for 'the sixth day before the Ides of June in the Year of the Lord 2010'.

In more modern writings this might be more simply expressed **VIII. IUN. MMX**.

Take your pick!

Comment: This is indeed the classical way to write the date, and I would recommend the classicla form. If anyone wants more details, [this older question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1943/79) might be interesting. I would add that if Iveta ever needs to read the date out loud, it's *ante diem sextum Idus Iunias anno Domini bis millesimo decimo*.

Comment: Good, but (I must have said this before sometime) if you are using the Roman style you ought to use the Julian (not Gregorian) calendar, where the equivalent is a.d. VII Kal. Iun.(26 May).

Comment: @fdb, that's too pedantic for words! How would anyone know whether it was Julian or Gregorian?  Anyway, it wasn't until 525 that Dionysius Exiguus ('Little Denis') worked out the now-accepted year in which the Christian Era should be considered to have begun. We might, of course, be really classical (and in the absence of consuls) write AUC MMDCCLXIII.