# How to interpret "tertio" in the context of dates?

Tags: vocabulary, dates

I often see dates expressed as, for example, *tertio idus maias* where *idus* is the feminine accusative plural and *maias* is the adjective agreeing with *idus* relating to the month of May. So, the question is how to interpret *tertio* which can either be an adverb mean "thirdly", or potentially as the ablative form of the adjective *tertius* meaning third which is modifying an implied *die*. In other words, *tertio (die) idus maias* ("on/regarding the third day before/towards the ides of May"). An example of a full sentence is:

*Tertio idus Maias Fidis mane oritur, significat tempestatem.* ("Third ides of May, the Lyre rises in the morning, it signifies a storm.")

So, the question is: is *tertio* the adverb or the ablative of the adjective *tertius*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/how-do-you-write-dates-in-latin