# What does a.d.v. stand for in dates?

Tags: calendarium, dates

What does a.d.v stand for in dates? For example:

*Is dies erat a. d. v. Kal. Apr. L. Pisone A. Gabinio consulibus.* --*De Bello Gallico* 1.6

Answer (score 9):

Ante diem quintum.

That is to say, a. d. v. Kal. Apr. = ante diem quintum Kalendas Apriles = 28th of March.

Comment: [This question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1943/79) explains the counting and month naming issues if anyone is confused.

Comment: So, would that be the fifth or the sixth day before the Kalends?

Comment: @TylerDurden the fourth: 31 (pridie) - 30 (a. d. III.) - 29 (IV) - 28 (V).